# Calling two methods from Controller only after button click inside first method

Tags: java, swing

My Controller - calls methodA in Class X.
I would like Class A to have a Jbutton which calls Method B. MethodB is also in ClassX.

Basically both methods create Java Swing components, but I would like them to appear one after the other (B only appearing after button click in A).

My controller at the moment calls:

```
ClassX.methodA()
ClassX.methodB()
```

I would somehow like the controller to call ClassX.methodA(), and then ClassX.methodB() only once a JButton is clicked inside methodA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add actionlistener to the button in method A, and inside the handler method, you trigger method B

```
    JButton button = new JButton(" Method A");
    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            methodB();
        }
    });
```

Or, (*recommended way*) you can make Controller as observer of class A, so when the button is clicked, you notify Controller to trigger method B

```
    JButton button = new JButton(" Method A");
    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            //Notify controller that method A is clicked
            notifyObserver();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, the Observer method makes sense.